# Why is this ajax call only sending q and email?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have written the following ajax call but only the q and email parameters are being sent, I've tried replacing message as I thought that it may be a key word but that still didn't work. I'm lost for ideas now.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/functions.php',
    data: {
        q: 'need_help',
        email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
        message: $('input[name=message]').val()
    }
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Form Code:

```
<div class='form-group col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6'>
    <input class='form-control' type='email' name='email' placeholder='Your email'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6'>
    <textarea class='form-control' name='message' placeholder='What is your problem?'></textarea>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6'>
    <input id='button_submit' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary form-control' value='Send' name='need_help' data-loading-text='Sending...'>
</div>
```

Before you say it's not in a form the ajax call is sent out in an onClick on the submit button, also I only have a blank file for the ajax at the moment but I can see the error in the developer network tab.

Comment: HTML form/PHP, might be something in there too.

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  Does `$('input[name=message]')` find any elements?  Does `.val()` return anything for those elements?  In the browser's network tools, is anything sent in the POST request for that parameter?  Does the server-side code receive that parameter?  There's nothing specifically wrong with the code you posted, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: When looking at the request in the network tab only the q and email parts of the data object are sent

Comment: [`I guess I was right`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579597/why-is-this-ajax-call-only-sending-q-and-email#comment38075906_24579597) - it does pay off when showing full code from the get-go - `$guesswork=0;` ;-)

Comment: Haha yes you were indeed I'll be sure to in the future

Comment: You'd be surprised as to what some think may be irrelevant as code at times, when it turns out that a single line of code from a JS file or PHP/HTML is the root of the problem. Glad you found your solution, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
message: $('input[name=message]').val()
```

to

```
message: $('textarea[name="message"]').val()
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ you can select form elements without speech marks like that can't you?

Comment: You have no idea how much I just facepalmed when I saw this -.- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong selector:

```
    message: $('input[name=message]').val()
                ^^^^^---input field

<textarea class='form-control' name='message' placeholder='What is your problem?'>
 ^^^^^^^^---but it's actually a textarea
```

Try `$('textarea[name=message]')` instead.

Comment: Which is why it always pays when an OP posts full code (from the get-go).

Answer (score 0):

Message is a textarea, not an input, try changing that out and seeing if it shows up now.

```
message: $('textarea[name=message]').val()
```